# Django get foreign key data within views.py

Tags: python, django, web

I am starting off with django development and I am stuck getting some values out. In my mind it should be simple.

I have multiple models but I am having difficulty getting the area (county) from the event itself in my views. Below I have a very short sample of the event code (not really relevant however, if you need more just ask).

```
class Event(models.Model):
    organiser = models.ForeignKey(User)
    etc...
```

The problem is a single event can be advertised in multiple areas (limited on the event type). To make sure it's not a many to many I have defined an event county as below:

```
class EventCounty(models.Model):
    county = models.ForeignKey(county)
    event = models.ForeignKey(event)
```

Now the problem lies in the views, for my index page I want to show the 5 recently added and the 5 upcoming events. This is really simple as I can order by the date_added and event_date fields within Event. However, I am not really sure how to access the county from this data.

I am assuming I could just write the sql statement myself (it's simple) however, if possible I would like to stay within the django framework and use their code. I believe the below statement would be something I will need to translate (it may or may not work!).

```
select county from EventCounty where event in (listevents);
```

If anybody knows how I can get this to work I will be grateful!

Thanks in advance,

Luke

Comment: Why not use a `county` field in your `Event` model, rather than creating an `EventCounty` model that makes the database larger and slower?

Answer (score 1):

Check select_related if you want include referenced objects

```
EventCounty.objects.select_related('event').filter(....)
```

[select_related on Django doc. sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)

Answer (score 0):

As you defined a event can be in multiple counties. So event object has set of `County` you can access them as

```
event_obj.county_set.all()
```

`county_set()` is `RelatedManager` so you can do `.filter()`, `.get()` etc on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
objs = EventCounty.objects.filter(event__in=listevents)
countyList = []
for obj in objs:
    countyList.append(obj.county)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the EventCount model holds a ForeignKey to Event model it is rather simple - ForeignKey enables "backward" relation (see [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)). In your case this could look like:

```
events = Event.objects.all().order_by(<put your date field here>)[:5]
```

To get a list (or QuerySet) off all EventCounty objects for e.g. first Event object just use:

```
events_county = events[0].eventcounty_set.all()
```

As suggested by Rohan the eventcounty_set is a RelatedManager which means you can work with it like with a QuerySet (filter, exclude, order, slice etc.)